# sum-sets in a finite field

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups, permutation-groups, sumsets

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field, $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}\subset\mathbb{F}_p^*$ a $k$-element set, for $k<p$. $\mathfrak{S}_k=$permutation gp.

> **Question.** Is it true there is always a $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_k$ such that the following are pair-wise distinct in $\mathbb{F}_p$?
>   $$a_{\pi(1)}, \,a_{\pi(1)}+a_{\pi(2)},\,a_{\pi(1)}+a_{\pi(2)}+a_{\pi(3)},\,\dots, \,a_{\pi(1)}+\cdots+a_{\pi(k)}.$$

**EDIT.** Due to Julian Rosen's example, I change $A$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ (non-zero elements).

Comment: $A=\{0,1,-1\}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What if we remove $0$?

Comment: More generally, take A disjoint union -A for certain A: you won't get much more than half way without getting a repeat. (Actually, that may not hold.  Hmm.)  Gerhard "Wonders About Big Uncertain A" Paseman, 2017.03.19.

Comment: This is actually a known open problem. I do not have any reference (and not sure anything has been published on it, just because there are no results to publish, as far as I am aware), but I remember for instance discussing it with Yong-Gao Chen and Zhi-Wei Sun a year and a half ago.

Comment: is symmetric gp = $S_k$ the symmetric group on $k$ elements?

Comment: If this is indeed "well-known", then can someone provide some reference? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took me some effort to find the references you were requesting in your comment, but here they are eventually:

- [Ordering subsets of the cyclic group to give distinct partial sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164300/ordering-subsets-of-the-cyclic-group-to-give-distinct-partial-sums/203111#comment503832_203111) (posted to MO April 2014);
- [Geometry, Number Theory and Graph Theory of n-gon, permutation and graph labeling?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209408/geometry-number-theory-and-graph-theory-of-n-gon-permutation-and-graph-labelin/209496#209496) (posted to MO June 2015);
- ["On partial sums in cyclic groups"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06872) by D. Archdeacon, J. Dinitz, A. Mattern, and D. Stinson, (*J. Combin. Math. Combin. Comput.* **98** (2016), 327–342).

As one can see, the problem is around for over 15 years at least.

Comment: Wow! That is incredible. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 6):

I first learned about this problem from Éric Balandraud (in 2013). So I wrote to him a couple of days ago, and he has just sent me an e-mail explaining that the question dates back (at least) to 1971. Éric attributes it to Erdős and Graham: He hasn't provided me with a reference (he is in the desert these days), but I will come back and update this answer as soon as I hear from him again.

*Update (March 31, 2017).* I've just got a new message from Éric Balandraud. Below is an excerpt.

---

Here is the reference:

> R. Graham, *On sums of integers taken from a fixed sequences*, Proc.
>   Wash. State Univ. Conf. on Number Theory (1971), 22-40.

The question is stated as Conjecture 10 on page 36. It also appears in:

> P. Erdős and R. Graham, *Old and new problems and results in combinatorial
>   number theory*, Monographie N28 de L'Enseignement Mathématiques,
>   Université de Genève (1980).

The conjecture is stated there on page 95.

---